# A simple Checkout Button?

Tags: paypal

I am using the simple paypal-provided HTML buttons, with 'add to cart' buttons.

Does anyone know the simple code to send the user to the checkout page?

For instance, a user has added an item to their cart, then clicked on the continue shopping button, how do they return to this cart page and/or checkout page without adding another item?

Thanks!

Comment: I've looked all through the paypal website and searched this, but found nothing.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When you create a standard shopping cart button with PayPal you get 2 code snippets back.  One is for the cart button and the other is for a View Cart button.  You would need to make sure and place the View Cart button somewhere on the page so that users can bring that back up without adding an item.

Comment: Thanks VERY much!! I knew it was simple, just couldn't find it anywhere!